# ReactDOM.render producing error element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use React router to display the correct page based on the url, basic stuff. Only issue is I'm getting an error I've never seen before. Here it is:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Home`.

Not sure why I'm seeing this. Hopefully you all can see something I'm missing.
Here's the code sample for my index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

function doRender() {

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>
            <div>
                <App/>
            </div>
        </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
}

doRender();

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And here's the App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components/Home';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And last, here's the code for the Home page :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../index.css';
import MenuBar from '../SubComponents/MenuBar';
import bgVideo from '../Media/bg-video.mp4';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className='MenuBar'>
                    <MenuBar/>
                </div>
                <div className="bg-video">
                    <video loop autoPlay>
                        <source src={bgVideo} type="video/mp4"/>
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Is MenuBar a default export?

Comment: Yes, it's a default export that I have set up as a menu I can import and use on every page. I'll post the code later today when I get home.